# Can I use preprocessor to check for included reference?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm looking to add CsvHelper to some of my C# projects (they all reference the same core library, but I can't add references to that). Is there a way to execute a code path if and only if a reference is in the project?

I'm trying to add a utility function that depends on it, otherwise if it isn't included the utility function will return null or empty list.

For example:

```
my code my code

#if CsvHelper_IS_AVAILABLE
    // load it
    // use it
#endif

my code my code
```

The root problem is my core library isn't the single source for references, in fact it doesn't seem possible to add references to library projects at all. So I have to maintain 20 references (all duplicated) across 20+ projects.

EDIT:

This question asked 7 years ago. C# 3.0... But has this gotten better?
[To check wether a specific project reference exists (C# Code, Preprocessor Directives ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093796/to-check-wether-a-specific-project-reference-exists-c-code-preprocessor-direc)

Comment: Intellisense does a decent job of guessing wich Reference you need based on code and Referenced DLL's. And you can also order the refactor to "remove unused References". In the end, what the compiler will work with is the fully Qualified typename. Includes are only a way to prevent you from needing to write the full name every time.

Comment: If you have  class that you can not inherit or change the implementation, the workaround is encapsualtion. MVVM programmers in particular have to make heavy use of Encapsulation to turn Model Clases into ViewModel classes with Properties that have ChangeNotification.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to avoid adding a reference to a project not a "using". Projects have dependencies like Sqlite or Win2d etc. So I'd like to leverage CsvHelper only for projects that really need it. Otherwise Im stuck updating dependencies and breaking things if they conflict with other nugget packages for example.

Comment: The code I am talking about lives in a common library. The problem really is I can't add these references in one place for all my projects. I have to manage then in 20+ projects.

Comment: Basically you want to have a "Master List" of includes, that are just inserted into every one of those 20 projects by the Pre-Processor? Or do you want a master list of References (those DLL that are needed) wich is the step before includes? I know that UWP has some limited support for Optional References (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml). It was designed for "apps that can run on a anything from Smartwatch to Server" and adapt accordingly.